# Have PLC Controller Listen/Send Custom TCP Packets?

Tags: tcp, plc

I would like to be able to communicated with PLC controllers, so that I can send and receive custom commands on the PLC.

My idea of being able to do this was to have a TCP listener on the PLC that could read TCP incoming packets on a specific port, and execute routines based on the commands in the packets. It could also send information back via TCP/IP.

This would allow me to write software in multiple languages such as C#, PHP, JavaScript, etc. so that software can be used on any platform such as Windows, iOS, Android, etc. to issue commands to the PLC. This would also mean you do not need the PLC software (which can be costly) to view or control the PLC.

I am not a PLC programmer, so I do not know if PLC has the capability of sending and receive custom TCP packets. I would like to know that a) if it is possible b) how feasible it would be to do this and c) what exactly I should research so that I can accomplish this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds a bit like reinventing the wheel. You want to make something like KepServerEX?

http://www.kepware.com/kepserverex/

There are also two things to consider - one is the ability to interface with the PLC to share data (ie: for a custom HMI) and the other is to program the PLC.  For the latter you still need the control software from the manufacturer unless you're willing to reverse engineer and re-write it from the ground up.

Keep in mind, also, that PLCs don't work the same way that other software does.  There are no functions or procedures or classes or objects or even really any "commands", per se.  A PLC is a system which executes a continuous fixed program of mostly raw logic rules and calculations.  A typical interface to an HMI involves reading and writing directly to/from logic bits and word data (ie:hardware memory locations) which represent the current state of the machine.  OPC already does this just fine so I'm not quite sure what you're going for.

If you're looking for a cheap/free alternative to a full commercial package, something here may work for you :

http://www.opcconnect.com/freesrv.php

Comment: This may be suitable. I am understanding that you would write a program in say C# to communicate with the KEPServerEX, and that would communicate with the PLC? Is it possible though to not use 3rd party software so there's no costs and strictly speak to the PLC with custom TCP messages?

Comment: I'm sure it's possible if you wanted to torture yourself or to do it as an academic exercise, but I doubt you could find an economical way to do it - it would certainly cost MUCH more in developer time to re-write everything rather than to just purchase a proper solution which already adheres to OPC standards.  Generally speaking, if you need the power of an industrial PLC then the cost of the software should probably be minimal compared to the risk of downtime and equipment failure and other capital costs.  $2k is peanuts when you're talking about >$1M piece of equipment...

Comment: The control I want over the PLC via TCP is minimal. For example I may only want the PLC to be able to listen to a couple TCP message such as run and stop. Therefore it seems overkill to have a server running to communicate with a single PLC that only needs to know a few messages.

Comment: So, this is a different beast altogether.  OPC allows you to exchange only data with a PLC - it does not allow any executive control (ie:change run modes, reprogram, etc.).  In fact, this would generally a *very bad idea* if your PLC is used for anything remotely important.  Communication protocols for these types of functions are proprietary and, afaik, not publicly available.  What are you trying to do anyway?  How can you afford an Allan Bradley PLC and not RSLogix?  HMI software should never need to stop or start a PLC - this probably means your approach is wrong.

Comment: We have an AB controller with the RSLogix software. You have to run the HMI made with Rockwell software to control the PLC. That means anybody who wants to use turn on or off a control on the PLC needs a computer with Rockwell software and the HMI. What I want to do, is have the PLC listen for simple TCP messages on a port. I can then write a simple exe in C# or something in PHP so that people could shoot a simple "run/stop" message to the controller from a computer without Rockwell software, or say even their cell phone.

Comment: You won't be able to change the run mode of the PLC this way (if you know what that means and if I understand you correctly when you say "run/stop").  OPC will allow you to read and write data to the PLC to change its program flow (ie: to turn on/off bits and modify data used in the program).  The fastest, best, and cheapest solution I can think of is to have a KepDirect server and custom HMI application running on a system beside the PLC.  The custom HMI can deal with network requests from anywhere you want and can handle interfacing with the PLC.

Comment: This will allow you to use your own communication protocol for all your devices and will take the PLC out of the loop.  It would recommend strongly against having a PLC with an open TCP port to a network - the PLC<->DataServer link should be totally private.  What is the application, anyway?  This can't be an industrial installation... school project?

Comment: For clarification on the run/stop; imagine my PLC controls a light bulb with a shunt. I would send a TCP message to the PLC from an exe written in C# on any computer or from a web page running on any platform. The TCP message would tell the PLC to open or close the shunt - thus controlling the light bulb. I can now control the PLC (as much as I need to) on any platform which can be given to many people without requiring each person to have a licensed copy of RSLogix or knowledge on how to use the HMI running on RSLogix.

Comment: Ok, so this is a simple data transfer.  PLCs also have operating modes (usually called "Run", "Stop", "Monitor", "Program", etc) which cannot be changed with simple data exchange.  It may be possible to hack together a partial low level driver to talk directly to the PLC but I still wouldn't recommend this approach unless this is for nothing but playing around or an academic experiment.  With an OPC data server and custom HMI (written in C# also, if you like) linked to the system you can write all of your auxiliary software to talk to your HMI/server.  This is probably the cleanest approach.

Comment: Added new link in main answer - some possibly workable alternatives

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, when referred to "Run/Stop" you mean for the PLC to 'Start' or 'Stop' scanning the code and updating its I/O. If this is the situation, it would be perfectly suitable to add a Scan_If_On bit (which will be written by a TCP Command) in parallel connection with the "Start" bit controlled by the HMI.
This way, there will be 2 forms of "Starting" the process controlled by the PLC. HMI and TCP.